# Use an Expression as Part of the Cache Key in an Azure yml Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I want to create a cache key from an expression in cache step located in a steps template. Since caches are imutable, I want to start with a clean cache every week or every months. My template file looks like this:

```yaml
# steps-tpl.yml
steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: compiler-cache | "<expression>" | "$(Agent.JobName)" | "$(Build.SourceBranch)" | "$(Build.SourceVersion)"
    restoreKeys: |
      compiler-cache | "<expression>" | "$(Agent.OS)" | "$(Agent.JobName)" | "$(Build.SourceBranch)" |  "$(Build.SourceVersion)"
      compiler-cache | "<expression>" | "$(Agent.OS)" | "$(Agent.JobName)" | "$(Build.SourceBranch)"
      compiler-cache | "<expression>" | "$(Agent.OS)" | "$(Agent.JobName)" | "refs/heads/master"
    path: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/ccache
  displayName: 'ccache/clcache: Warm up cache'
```

The expression should give me a different value each week of the year or for simplicity, the number of the current month.

I tried different things for expression and none of them worked. Firs I tried to put the expression into a parameter default value which didn't work. Then I tried to put the expression directly in place like this:

```
"${{ format('{0:MM}', pipeline.startTime) }}"
```

which didn't work either. And neither this:

```
"$[format('{0:MM}', pipeline.startTime)]"
```

I guess run-time expressions are not available outside a script context.

I even tried to set an environment variable in a step before the caching:

```
    echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=COMPILER_CACHE_KEY_PREFIX,isOutput=true]$[ counter(format("{0:yyyMMdd}", pipeline.startTime), 7) ]'
```

and to use that with `$(previousStep.COMPILER_CACHE_KEY_PREFIX)` which didn't work either.

How can I put such an expression into the cache key? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work directly in the Cache task, but this worked for me:

```
variables:
  cacheKeyDay: $[format('{0:ddMMyyyy}', pipeline.startTime)]

- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: $(cacheKeyDay)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar. What worked for me was setting a variable in a Powershell task, then using it with the syntax that expands at runtime:

```
variables:        
    - name: projectFolder
      value: ''


 # assign temporary variable resultfolder to variable projectFolder
 - powershell: |
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectFolder]$(resultfolder)"
   displayName: Save project folder path

 # refer to projectFolder, not the temporary variable resultfolder
 - task: Cache@2
   inputs:
     key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(projectFolder)/packages.lock.json'
     restoreKeys: |
      nuget | "$(Agent.OS)"
     path: $(NUGET_PACKAGES)
   displayName: Cache NuGet packages
```

The Cache task outputs the following:

```
Resolving key:
 - nuget                                 [string]
 - "Windows_NT"                          [string]
 - D:\a\1\s\PTS_Tasks/packages.lock.json [file] --> 811E162D4016AFBA61F7850XXXXXXXXXXXXX366DFAC37C757FC4D4F49992
Resolved to: nuget|"Windows_NT"|/9Pr8Jh9L66tny00XXXXXXXXXXnL23DoLKFCDGhG8=
```

Showing that the variable `projectFolder` has been expanded correctly.

So perhaps execute your expression inside the Powershell script, then assign the result to a variable.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I asked for. I need an expression that is not fixed, but changes depending on the date.

Comment: OK. My suggestion is to use a Powershell task to do that, then save it in a variable.

Comment: Yes, i see, but i doubt that the cache step sees the actual content of your variable that you have assigned. I think it will see an empty string. Are you really sure it works?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue with a workaround. First a script to generate the value I need for the cache key, then writing this value to a file und then using the file fingerprint as the cache value.

```
  - bash: |
      CACHEKEY=$(find -s ./src -type f -exec cat {} \;|md5)
      CACHEKEY="${CACHEKEY}-${{parameters.jobname}}"
      echo $CACHEKEY
      echo $CACHEKEY > cachekey.txt
    displayName: 'get hash of all folders, write value to file'
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'cachekey.txt'
      path: $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)
      cacheHitVar: 'CacheRestored'
```